# Learning to Surf in Goa - Your advice

Tags: water-sports, surfing

I am travelling to Goa in March and I am mostly crazy about water. Elementally, closest to it. Started swimming an year back and still a very naive swimmer but mostly comfortable with it.

I want to learn surfing. It's a short trip of 4 days but I am pretty much fine with giving all of the 4 days to Surfing. What's the best way to go about it? Schools/Instructors/suggestions- Anything that I should know about to be closer to being able to learn surfing in that time.

(Sorry if I am sounding over-optimistic about learning it in that short period of time - Feel free to offer a reality check if you think it's futile to plan it in such short duration.)

Comment: In general, four days is not long enough to "learn" a new skill, but it is plenty of time to progress from knowing nothing to knowing something and getting a head-start when you can spend more time on surfing -- or whatever.  So go for it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely do it, you can make enormous progress in 4 days!  But take safety seriously in the ocean:

1. Buy your own leash and carefully check that the connection to the rental surfboard is very secure.  If you are anything but a very experienced swimmer then becoming separated from your surfboard in the ocean may be an unpleasant or dangerous experience.  I’ve personally seen enough old failing Velcro on rental leashes that I would not trust my safety to them.
2. Surf with other people who can paddle over to you if you are separated from your board somehow anyway.  This sounds obvious but early morning/late dusk waves with no one on them can be tempting...
3. Swim as much as you can before you go to get as fit as possible.  4 days of surfing will be a physically demanding experience, the better shape you’re in when you arrive the more fun you will have.